# mysql, how to give priority to a cell with a particular value

Tags: mysql

In a give table I want to select the row with the maximum value in column-A, but in the same time if there are 2 or more rows that have a maximum value a want to get the row where the value in column-B is not null, if there is one, otherwise I just get the first row with the maximum value even if the value in Column B is null.

In summary:

1. first choice : Column-A maximum, Column-B Not null

   ```
      in case such a row does not exist
   ```
2. second choice : Column-A maxim, Column-B Null

Is it possible to write a single query with this constrain or do I have to create 2 queries with some logic in between?

Comment: edit your question with sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple columns with `ORDER BY` like below

```
SELECT columnA,columnB
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY columnA DESC, columnB DESC
```

It'll order by columnA first descending order, then columnB in descending order the null will be the last choice.

add a `LIMIT 1` at end of query if you just one row returned.

Answer (score 0):

Below Query will do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM tableA where columnA=(select max(columnA) from tableA) order by columnB desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline view to return the maximum value of col_a, and then do a join to get all the rows that have the same col_a value, then get the maximum value of col_b from those rows.

For example:

```
 SELECT s.col_a
      , MAX(t.col_b) AS col_b
   FROM ( SELECT MAX(r.col_a) AS col_a
            FROM mytable r
        ) s
   JOIN mytable t
     ON t.col_a = s.col_a
```